# Display different shipping rate depening on taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, commerce

I would like to offer a different flat shipping to users depending on what taxonomy terms the product they have in their cart.

If a product tagged with "postage rate 1"  I would like to display shipping rate 1. If they have a product tagged with shipping rate 2 I would like to display shipping rate 2.
I would also like to if possible make it so that if the cart has items with each of the tags then one item shipping rate would win through (the most expensive one to cover costs I would think)

I have had a go with rules but I cannot figure out how to get the different shipping rates to display on taxonomy terms.  I do have the commerce rules extra module installed if that will peform part of the solution

Thank you for looking

Answer (score 1):

I needed the exact thing for my webshop. Couldn't find it anywhere so a friend of mine made this module which works great!
https://drupal.org/project/commerce_taxonomy_conditions

On my site every product has either the taxonomy term 'letter' or 'package'
And then with that module you can add an extra condition to your shippingmethods to only use the products which that specific term.

If you are still in need for it then try it out :)